# Enforce Tag Value Validation in Azure (eg Format should a date 2022-07-24)

Tags: azure, validation, tagging

I will like to enforce an Azure Resource Tag value to allow a particular date format, the tag in question is a date so I want it in the format YYYY-MM-DD, but with my code below, users can still create the tags successfully without using the tagging convention.

```
{
  "if": {
    "not": {
      "field": "tags.date",
      "match": "####-##-??"
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "deny"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `tags[date]` instead of `tags.date` for the field. Also, I think you should use "####-##-##" for the match, since the `??` would match letters rather than numbers.

I assigned a policy definition with this to my resource group to test it, and hit an error as expected if I tried to create a date tag with "xyz" value, for example.

```
{
  "if": {
    "not": {
      "field": "tags[date]",
      "match": "####-##-##"
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "deny"
  }
}
```